# Scala priority queue not maintaining ordering

Tags: scala, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

I want this to be in order based on price...

```
final case class Case(price: Int) {}
```

But it's actually a significantly bigger case class that I removed fields from. I want to sort it like this...

```
val queue = PriorityQueue.empty[Case](Ordering.by((_: Case).price).reverse)
```

^ Sorted by descending price.

Now I want that sorting to stay...

```
queue.enqueue(Case(price = 2))
println(queue.toString)

queue.enqueue(Case(price = 3))
println(queue.toString)

queue.enqueue(Case(price = 4))
println(queue.toString)

queue.enqueue(Case(price = 1))
println(queue.toString)

queue.enqueue(Case(price = 0))
println(queue.toString)
```

But my output isn't sorted on the fourth and fifth line...

```
PriorityQueue(Case(2))
PriorityQueue(Case(2), Case(3))
PriorityQueue(Case(2), Case(3), Case(4))
PriorityQueue(Case(1), Case(2), Case(4), Case(3))
PriorityQueue(Case(0), Case(1), Case(4), Case(3), Case(2))
```

Also, the `foreach` method isn't iterating in order...

```
queue.foreach{ q =>
  print(q + ", ")
}
```

Prints...

```
Case(0), Case(1), Case(4), Case(3), Case(2),
```

How do I make my queue remain ordered on descending price?

Answer (score 7):

Per the [Scala Documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue), printing the queue will not show the priority:

> Only the dequeue and dequeueAll methods will return methods in
>   priority order (while removing elements from the heap). Standard
>   collection methods including drop, iterator, and toString will remove
>   or traverse the heap in whichever order seems most convenient.
>
> Therefore, printing a PriorityQueue will not reveal the priority order
>   of the elements, though the highest-priority element will be printed
>   first. To print the elements in order, one must duplicate the
>   PriorityQueue (by using clone, for instance) and then dequeue them

Thus if you want to see the elements in order you will need something like this:

```
scala> val queue = PriorityQueue.empty[Case](Ordering.by((_: Case).price).reverse)
queue: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Case] = PriorityQueue()

scala> queue += Case(2) += Case(3) += Case(4) += Case(1) += Case(0)
res1: queue.type = PriorityQueue(Case(0), Case(1), Case(4), Case(3), Case(2))

scala> while (queue.size > 0) println(queue.dequeue)
Case(0)
Case(1)
Case(2)
Case(3)
Case(4)
```

Or you can get the ordered collection using `dequeueAll`:

```
scala> val queue = PriorityQueue.empty[Case](Ordering.by((_: Case).price).reverse)
queue: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Case] = PriorityQueue()

scala> queue += Case(2) += Case(3) += Case(4) += Case(1) += Case(0)
res2: queue.type = PriorityQueue(Case(0), Case(1), Case(4), Case(3), Case(2))

scala> val ordered = queue.dequeueAll                                                                      
ordered: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Case] = Vector(Case(0), Case(1), Case(2), Case(3), Case(4)) 

scala> ordered.foreach(println)                                                                            
Case(0)                                                                                                    
Case(1)                                                                                                    
Case(2)                                                                                                    
Case(3)                                                                                                    
Case(4)
```

Based on discussions 
[here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4833), there is no way to retrieve the elements in order without destroying the queue via dequeuing. This seems to be intrinsic to the implementation of the underlying data structure (a binary heap).

Answer (score 1):

Printing the priority queue may not return the elements in the order.

What is guaranteed though is that `head` always returns the lowest (as per your ordering) element and repeated `dequeue`ing dequeues elements in the order specified by the `Ordering`.

When I do:

```
queue.dequeue()
queue.dequeue()
queue.dequeue()
queue.dequeue()
queue.dequeue()
```

I see:

```
res10: Case = Case(0)
res11: Case = Case(1)
res12: Case = Case(2)
res13: Case = Case(3)
res14: Case = Case(4)
```

Comment: But when I iterate through the elements with `foreach` I want to iterate through them in order from lowest to highest.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette You can probably `dequeue` using `while` with `size`?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the scala default implementation is not inplace dequeue while the priority queue elements are equal. You could use implement the inplace dequeue as blow:

```
class PriorityQueueTest{
 implicit val ord: Ordering[(Any,Int)] = Ordering.by(_._2)

 var queue = mutable.PriorityQueue[(Any,Int)]()

 def inplaceDeque(number:Int): Seq[(Any,Int)] ={
  var res: Seq[(Any,Int)] = Seq()
    res =queue.take(number).toSeq
    queue =queue.drop(number)
  res
 }
}
```

[image]